# Application of Hölder to prove $L^q \subset L^p$ for $1\leq p\leq q<\infty$ with Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

I'm working on the following problem and got stuck. Any help would be really appreaciated.
Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $1\leq p \leq q < \infty$. Show that for any $f\in L^q([a,b])$ the following holds:

$$\frac{\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_p}{(b-a)^{1/p}} \leq \frac{\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_q}{(b-a)^{1/q}}$$

Thus $L^q([a,b])\subset L^p([a,b]).$

So I noticed that we could maybe use Hölder inequality with $g=\chi_{(a,b)}$, then $g$ is measurable and integrable, in particular:

$$g\in L^q,L^p$$
$$\lvert\lvert g\rvert\rvert_p = \left(\int\lvert g\rvert^p\right)^{1/p}= (b-a)^{1/p}$$
Then, if we suppose $f\in L^p$. By Hölder:

$$\lvert\lvert f \cdot g\rvert\rvert_1=\left(\int\lvert f\cdot g\rvert \right) \leq \lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_q\cdot \lvert\lvert g\rvert\rvert_p = \lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_q \cdot (b-a)^{1/p} $$

If we use Hölder again:

$$\frac{\lvert\lvert f \cdot g\rvert\rvert_1}{(b-a)^{1/p}} \leq \frac{\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_p}{(b-a)^{1/p}}\cdot\lvert\lvert g\rvert\rvert_q = \frac{\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_p}{(b-a)^{1/p}}\cdot (b-a)^{1/q} \leq \lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_q$$

Which would give us the inequality. But this would only be true if:

1. $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1$
2. We don't know if $f\in L^p$

What am I missing or doing wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last inequality seems obscure.
Anyway, perhaps you were hindered by the usual setting of Holder, so let me rephrase it for you :
$$ \left( \int |h| \right)^m \left( \int |g| \right)^n \ge \left( \int |h|^{\frac{m}{m+n}}.|g|^{ \frac{n}{m+n}} \right)^{m+n}$$

for all measurable functions $f,g$ and positive real number $m,n$.

Your desired equality is the special case of Holder with :
$$ h:= |f|^q ; g:= \mathbb{1}_{[a,b]} ; m=1$$
and $n>0$ satisies $ p =q\frac{m}{m+n}$ (note that $p<q$)

Comment: So with this setting it is okay to use $m=1$?

Comment: Yeah, because when you taking roots to the power of $(m+n)$ of both sides, you'll get the usual Holder's inequality.